# Getting cell color from Powerpoint table cell via VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Hi I have a Table on a Powerpoint slide and I am trying to get the fill color for that cell to use elsewhere.

I am using:

```
Set c = colorTable.Rows(2).Cells(1) 
sColor = c.Shape.Fill.BackColor
```

But it is always returning 16777215 which is white.  The cell is clearly not white.  Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

Use **.ForeColor**, not .BackColor.

Comment: Either way gives me the same 16777215, but I need the background fill color anyway.

Comment: I test all code before posting, so I know .ForeColor will give the fill of a conventionally colored cell. It gives the same result as using the Format Shape task pane>Fill>Solid Fill>Color command. If you fill the cell with a Pattern Fill, you'll notice color pickers for the Foreground (ForeColor) and Background (BackColor). That the only time BackColor displays. If the cell is unconventionally colored (Gradient or Picture fill), you would get a different result.